# Сохранить все атрибуты элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент:

```html
<input type="text" class="ctrl-textbox" placeholder="Text..." id="input-text-1">
```

Я пытаюсь сохранить новые значения каждого атрибута:

```js
function save(ctrl) {    
     var element = $(ctrl);     
        
     $(ctrl[0].attributes).each(function() {      
      ctrl[this.name] = this.value;
     });       

 }
```

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вы атрибуты хотите получить для элемента element или для чего? Какой в этом случае смысл переменной element? Также вы сначала используете ctrl[0], а свойства присваиваете ctrl.

Comment: Приведите пример вызова функции `save()`. В частности, интересует тип аргумента `ctrl`.

Comment: для элемента element

Comment: @tutankhamun 
var div_ctrl = $("#" + ctrl_id);
var ctrl = div_ctrl.find("input")[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `ctrl` это jQuery-объект, то поля `attributes` у него нет, чтобы получить атрибуты первого DOM-элемента нужно обращаться к ним `ctrl.get(0).attributes`;

Вот половина ответа на ваш вопрос. Чтобы перебрать все аттрибуты первого элемента воспользуйтесь конструкцией:

```
$.each(ctrl.get(0).attributes, function (ix, attr) {
    // Тут уже распоряжайтесь параметрами attr.name и attr.value
    // На ваше усмотрение
}
```

Если поясните более полно что именно вы хотите в результате (и какую цель вы преследуете), я дополню ответ.

Comment: ctrl - элемент типа input. var div_ctrl = $("#" + ctrl_id); (div в котором находится ctrl) var ctrl = div_ctrl.find("input")[0]; (сам ctrl) я получаю объект (допустим values) в котором хранятся новые значения этих атрибутов. var obj = { id = 'newID' ,type = 'newType'...}

Comment: @serf Если у вас есть объект с парами `имя_аттрибута: значение`, задачка решается в одно действие при помощи jQuery: `ctrl.attr(obj);` См. http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributes

Comment: пробовал еще так
`function save(ctrl, values){
var element = $(ctrl);
$(element[0].attributes).each(function() {
ctrl[this.name] = values[this.name];
});
}`

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, в чем состоит ваша проблема и зачем вы именно так делаете. Посмотрите [сюда](http://jsfiddle.net/rwa13pe7/). В строке 7 меняются сразу три параметра, которые заданы в переменной `obj`. Это не тот результат, который вы хотите получить?

Comment: пример оказался крайне полезен!

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#res1').textContent = document.getElementById('input-text-1').outerHTML;

d = document.createElement('div');
d.appendChild(document.getElementById('input-text-1').cloneNode(true));
document.querySelector('#res2').textContent = d.innerHTML;
```

```css
output {
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="ctrl-textbox" placeholder="Text..." id="input-text-1">
<output id=res1></output>
<output id=res2></output>
```